# How can I replay a swf movie on jquery button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have a webpage with several swf movies that is created in dreamweaver and outputs several object tags like such:

```
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="160" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="Banners Template/Example_160x600.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
    <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. --> 
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Banners Template/Example_160x600.swf" width="160" height="600">
      <!--<![endif]-->
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
      <div>
        <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
      </div>
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
</script>
```

I would like to do the following:

1. The Swf animation runs once through on page load(This is
   currently happening)
2. Once user clicks a 'Replay Movie' button,
   the swf it is associated with will replay until the movie finishes.

I have been trying to find some code that can utilize javascript or jQuery to either reload the contents of the object tag or replay the swf with no success. How can I replay a swf movie on jquery button click?

Answer (score 0):

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Ff7Mq/

**demo2:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/J6WQm/

capture the event and change the source of the file.
Or use your swf object to render the div again.

```
var initVideos = function () {
    var divs = $("ul li a");

    // bind your click event to the divs
    divs.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // use this when you're triggering anchor tags
        flashembed("videoArea", $(this).prop("href"));
        divs.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
};
```

Comment: While these are cool examples, they don't really address the issue I am having with using the bloated object tag that dreamweaver outputs. The main issue is that other(non-development) person will be inserting the swf's in dreamweaver. We need to be able to add the jquery code that will enable the movie to replay.